# Haskell: build a tree from a list

Tags: list, haskell, tree, higher-order-functions

Consider the following type:

```
data LTree a = Leaf a | Fork (LTree a) (LTree a)
```

Now consider the following function that lists the leaves of a tree, together with its depth

```
tolistdepth :: LTree a -> [(a,Int)]
tolistdepth (Leaf x) = [(x,0)]
tolistdepth (Fork e d) = map (\(x,n) -> (x,n+1)) (tolistdepth e ++ tolistdepth d)
```

I need help defining the following function

```
build :: [(a, Int)] -> LTree a
```

that calculates the inverse of the first function so that

```
build (tolistdepth a) = a
```

I don't even know where to start :)

---

I have managed to do the following:

```
build :: [(a, Int)] -> LTree a
build xs = let ys= map (\(x, n) -> (Leaf x, n)) xs
           in SOMETHING iterateUntil SOMETHING (buildAssist ys)

buildAssist :: [(LTree a, Int)] -> [(LTree a, Int)]
buildAssist [] = []
buildAssist [x] = [x]
buildAssist (x@(t1, n1):y@(t2, n2):xs) = if n1 == n2 then ((Fork t1 t2), n1 - 1):buildAssist xs
                                                     else x:(buildAssist (y:xs))
```

This way, I think I have dealt with when to fork. 
Now, how do I use buildAssist in my original function (if buildAssist is of any use of course)?

---

I believe I have figured it out.

Please let me know if this works:

```
build :: [(a,Int)] -> LTree a
build l = fst (buildaccum 0 l)

buildaccum :: Int -> [(a,Int)] -> (LTree a, [(a,Int)])
buildaccum n l@((a,b):t) |n==b = (Leaf a,t)
                         |n<b = (Fork e d, l2)
     where (e,l1) = buildaccum (n+1) l
           (d,l2) = buildaccum (n+2) l1
```

Comment: What can you assume about the argument to build? Not all possible inputs can be made into a tree.

Comment: @ChrisTaylor Assume that the input can be made into a tree. Thanks for pointing it out

Comment: I think you can use your `buildAssist` if you keep on calling it until you get to a single element.

Comment: @user5402 Could you elaborate on how I could do that?

Comment: I updated my answer. Once you get your approach working I'll post the solution I was thinking of.

Comment: Make sure your code works on this input: `[(A,3),(B,3),(C,2),(D,2),(E,2)]` which comes from `Fork (Fork (Fork (Leaf A) (Leaf B)) (Leaf C)) (Fork (Leaf D) (Leaf E))`

Comment: @user5402 I'm sorry. I still don't see which condition I should use in iterateUntil

Comment: `buildaccum` is very very close. I think you're just off by one in one spot. Try it on a simple example - e.g. `Fork (Leaf 1) (Leaf 2)`.

Comment: @user5402 I tried to compile my code in GHCi but got the following errors: Couldn't match expected type `(LTree a, [(a, Int)])'
                with actual type `LTree a'

Comment: this thread is getting quite long - open up another question and I'll answer it

Comment: @user5402 here is the new thread: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/21650802/error-in-list-to-tree

Comment: @user5402 Could you also provide me with the answer for my question about the condition in the iterateUntil function please? Edit my question if that is easier for you. Thanks :)

Comment: @user5402 Ok. Error in the first guard of buildaccum corrected

Comment: actually, the `iterateUntil` approach won't work. your `buildAccum` function is very close to correct.

Comment: @user5402 Ok thanyou very much for all your help. Could you provide your solution now? Thanks

Comment: Why are you recursing into the left subtree with `n+1` and the right subtree with `n+2`? Depth is counted from the top of the tree so the subtrees of a `Fork` should have the same depth, right?

Answer (score 6):

I'll give you a hint which demonstrates a helpful technique when parsing lists.

What really is at work here is a function like this:

```
build' :: [(a,Int)] -> (LTree a, [(a,Int)])
```

That is, `build'` returns a `LTree a` and the rest of the input list it has not yet consumed.

In this form the definition of `build'` goes something like this:

```
build' [] = error "oops - bad input list"
build' ((a,n):xs) =
  if we are at a leaf node, return (LTree a, xs)
  if we decide we need to fork, then return (Fork e f,zs)
    where
      (e,ys) = build' ((a,n):xs)  -- parse the left branch
      (f,zs) = build' ys          -- parse the right branch
```

Note this is just pseudo-code, and there are important details missing which I am leaving as an exercise.

The interesting part is how the remaining input list is determined in the `Fork` case.
`ys` is the remaining input after parsing the left branch, and this is fed as input to `build'` to get the right branch, and the remaining input of that call to `build'` (`zs`) is returned as the remaining input from the original `build'` call.

Update:

To iterate a function `f` with starting value `x` until a certain condition `p`, follow this formula:

```
iterateUntil p f x = if p x then x else iterateUntil p f (f x)
```

Comment: Thankyou. That gave me an idea. I editted my question with what I have come up. Please also provide your solution. I always like to see different solutions to the same problem, helps me a lot in learning this language.

Comment: Ok that's a useful function. Regarding the problem at hand, I don't know when I want to stop iterating (e.g I don't know what my p should be in the above definition).