# Error in list to tree

Tags: list, haskell, tree

Consider the following type:

```
data LTree a = Leaf a | Fork (LTree a) (LTree a)
build :: [(a,Int)] -> LTree a
build l = fst (buildaccum 0 l)e
```

I have a list and want to build a tree

```
buildaccum :: Int -> [(a,Int)] -> (LTree a, [(a,Int)])
buildaccum n l@((a,b):t) |n==b = (Leaf a,t)
                         |n<b = (Fork e d, l2)
     where (e,l1) = buildaccum (n+1) l
           (d,l2) = buildaccum (n+2) l1
```

In ghci, I get the following error:

```
Couldn't match expected type (LTree a, [(a, Int)])' with actual type LTree a'
```

Can you spot the error, please?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`buildAccum` must return a pair type `(LTree a, [(a, Int)])`, but in your first guarded statement you return a raw `LTree a`: `Leaf a`.

Comment: Thanks for pointing it out. I eddited my question. Thanks for your help!